# Robots txt disallow on Blogger

Tags: seo, robots.txt

I have a blog in Blogger, so the URL structure is always like this:

```
www.example.com/2019/01/post.html
```

The problem is I **don't want** google to crawl  www.example.com/**2019** (it shows all posts of 2019) and www.example.com/**2019/01** (shows all posts of January).

Is there a way to block this in `robots.txt`, and allow the individual HTML posts to be crawled?

Answer (score 2):

Frankly, you're better off not disallowing the two date-related categories in your `robots.txt` file, and using the `noindex` meta tags on these category pages (`www.example.com/2019/` and `www.example.com/2019/01/`) instead. It will be less labor-intensive, and ensure that those pages are not in the SERPs. (A `robots.txt` directive does not guarantee that a page won't be indexed.) Just set the noindex robots meta tag on both category pages:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow">
```

If you absolutely must use the `robots.txt` file for this, you can use the `Allow` directive, which is sometimes referred to as nonstandard in SEO literature. However, as **MrWhite** points out below, "exactly how the different bots interpret these non-standard additions to `robots.txt` could warrant further testing," plus you might still get those pages indexed, so the category page level meta tag would be preferable. If you still want to use the `robots.txt` file, you'd include something like this:

```
User-agent: *  
Allow: /2019/*.html$  
Disallow: /2019/
```

That would disallow anything in the `2019` folder, including folders for each month. But Googlebot would be able to access anything in that folder that ends with ".html". You'd have to update this every year to keep it current.

This was also addressed on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42882200/robots-txt-disallow-folder-but-allow-files-within-folder

Comment: "not disallowing the two date-related categories" - I agree. In fact, I would think that if you disallowed the two date-related categories it would negatively affect the crawling/indexing of the "individual HTML posts", as those category pages link to the posts.

Comment: "`Allow` is obeyed only by Googlebot" - Moz is incorrect/out-of-date here (and would seem to be using a non-authoritative reference?). Whilst `Allow:` is non-standard, it has been [supported by most of the mainstream bots](https://yoast.com/ultimate-guide-robots-txt/#allow-directive) for many years. [BingBot certainly does support the `Allow:` directive](https://blogs.bing.com/webmaster/2012/05/03/to-crawl-or-not-to-crawl-that-is-bingbots-question/). Although exactly how the different bots interpret these non-standard additions to `robots.txt` could warrant further testing.

Comment: @MrWhite Thank you for pointing out the error re: Allow directive. I should have done more research on that, especially since I relied on Moz for this detail, but Moz is unfortunately not what it used to be. I updated the response to reflect your info.